# AlertDialog from non activity class. new activity class dose not work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I want to create an alert dialog on non-activity and knew that I can't do it in non activity unless I create an alert activity.

I implemented as follows but it doesn't work - if I click nothing changes.

This is the alert class call in non activity:

```
    Class alertDeletion=AlertDeletion.class;
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext,alertDeletion );
    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    if (getFlag()){ // do some thing }
```

this is the AlertDialog activity

```
public class AlertDeletion extends AppCompatActivity  {
private static boolean flag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_deletion);
    flag= confermation();
    finish();
}
public  boolean confermation(){
  //  boolean answer =false;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    alert.setTitle("Alert!!");
    alert.setMessage("Are you sure to delete ");
    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
           setFlag(true);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         setFlag(false);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog builder = alert.create();
    builder.show();
    return getFlag();
}
private void setFlag(boolean t){
 flag=t;
}
public static boolean getFlag(){
    return flag;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AlertDialog box in a non-Activity view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249256/alertdialog-box-in-a-non-activity-view)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getFlag()` use `alertDeletion.getFlag()` in the if condition `if (getFlag()){ // do some thing }`